# Using openxlsx to write a character vector across columns

Tags: r, openxlsx

I'm trying to write data across multiple columns in excel using a single vector as input. All my attempts, result in vertical placement.

[image: vertical placement of data]

What I want:

[image]

```
library(openxlsx)
vec <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")
writeData(wb, 1, vec,
  startCol = 1,
  startRow = 1,
  colNames = FALSE)

saveWorkbook(wb, "test1.xlsx", overwrite = T)
```

I have also manipulated the vector into a string incase there was something about the vector was causing new lines.

`vec <- paste(vec, sep = ",")`

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Try writing `t(vec)`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I deal with this in openxlsx.  You need to convert it to a different structure.  I don't know of a way to just tell openslsx to orient your vector horizontally.

```
library(openxlsx)
vec <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

wb3 <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb3, "Sheet1")
writeData(wb3, 1,  matrix(vec,ncol=length(vec)),
  startCol = 1,
  startRow = 1,
  colNames = FALSE)

saveWorkbook(wb3, "test1.xlsx", overwrite = T)
```